# How to transition between different body backgrounds onClick? (Attempt 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when you click the navigation buttons at the top of my page, they cause the background to change. I was partially successful but the background always switches back immediately and I would like each background to fade into the next one.
Here's the javascript on the first page with the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('li a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.cookie('currentImg', $('body').css('background-image') );
     $.cookie('nextImg', 'Tranquil.jpg');
});
</script>

<li class="item6" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#022D4D';" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor='#032F76';"><a href="Environment.php" onClick="EnvBack();" title="Environment" >Environment</a></li>
```

Here's the javascript on the new page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//on next page (Environment.php)

//#nextImage is a div covering the page with a z-index placing just above the body element
$('body').css('background-image', $.cookie('currentImg') );
$('#nextImage').css({
      visibility : 'hidden',
      backgroundImage : $.cookie('nextImg')
  //wait for image to load
}).load(function(){
     //set state to hidden, if it was hidden before rather than merely 
     //invisible the div will not load.
     //then fade in the new image producing a smooth transition
     $(this).css('visibility','visible').fadeIn(function(){
           //reset state of page
           $('body').css('background-image', $.cookie('nextImg') );
           $(this).remove();
     });
});
</script>
```

Here's the CSS for the body:

```
body
{
    background-image:url("abstract1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:font-family: Helvetica,Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#nextImage
{
    background-image="";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family:font-family: Helvetica,Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

When I jump to new page.. all the css is invisible instead of it transitioning

Comment: Of course it does, your setting a background color on mouseout, AFTER the background is set with click. So you first run your function on click (inline js should be avoided), then you're setting the background to a color on mouseout. You can't fade background images either, so you will have to fade the elements, and <body> is probably not the one you wan't to fade out, and Fresheyeball is partially correct, you will need two elements to cross fade, but onlu one to fade out then change image and fade in.

Comment: If the click event on your link isn't being suppressed, what's the point of changing the background image when it's clicked on?

Comment: The onmouseout changes the background color of the actual nav bar element.. not the body background. They're two different background changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much respect to VAShhh for catching refresh part of this equation.

First you need to transfer the current image setting to the new page via a cookie, the image can remain after refresh. In this example I am going to transfer both the current and the desired image. (jquery cookie plugin required)

```
//its important to use jQuery here so we have a normalized event object
$('li a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.cookie('currentImg', $('body').css('background-image') );
     $.cookie('nextImg', 'Tranquil.jpg');
});

//on next page (Environment.php)

//#nextImage is a div covering the page with a z-index placing just above the body element
$('body').css('background-image', $.cookie('currentImg') );
$('#nextImage').css({
      visibility : 'hidden',
      backgroundImage : $.cookie('nextImg')
  //wait for image to load
}).load(function(){
     //set state to hidden, if it was hidden before rather than merely 
     //invisible the div will not load.
     //then fade in the new image producing a smooth transition
     $(this).hide().css('visibility','visible').fadeIn(function(){
           //reset state of page
           $('body').css('background-image', $.cookie('nextImg') );
           $(this).remove();
     });
});
```

You cannot cross-fade between css background images on the same element. To achieve the effect you are looking for you will need a minium of two elements. One to hold the initial image, and the other to hold the new one. Place the new one over the old one (z-index) and fade the element with the new image in.

You might want to check out a jQuery plugin for this like: 
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index.html
http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/
http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/

Keep in mind you will also have to preload the next image in line BEFORE fading otherwise it will look shitty.

Here is an example of one that I wrote myself:

http://www.wideopenadventure.com/woa/

Comment: I think that the problem is that he's not preventing the default action for the onclick, so he sees the image changing but then he is redirected to the page he wants

Comment: That is not the nature of the question he asked. He is asking how to get the background to fade transition into the next image, he has stated that the image change itself already works.

Comment: In fact its the TITLE of the question! He does also need to prevent default with the code he presented.

Comment: Actually he is saying that he sees the background changing but then he switches back, so I assume the background is changing but then he's redirected to a page with the same layout and so the background "switches back"

Comment: But then both our answers are needed. He must prevent Default to stop the redirect, and also use a second element to create a transition.

Comment: ^Yeah I do need both answers.. can one of you give an example of how I might prevent the background from switching back? I understand why it is switching now. But I went to the cookies page for jquery and I'm not understanding exactly how to use them.

Comment: I edited my answer to demonstrate a full concept and approach to this problem.

Comment: I tried the above code but it just made all of the css on my page disappear after I clicked the link. I put the nextImage div right below body and put all my content inside of it.

Comment: @GavinSellers did you read my code and write a version that conforms to you needs? Or just copy and paste what I wrote?

Comment: I wrote in all the div ids from my site but I don't know how to modify it beyond that.

Comment: @GavinSellers then I'm sorry to say you are lost my friend. I can't help any farther without actually seeing your site. Feel free to hit my on skype, just do a search from fresheyeball and I will help you out.

Comment: I just did away with the click function and cookies and instead used javascript on the new page to set the background.. achieves essentially the same effect.

Comment: @GavinSellers Nice work. The whole point of the cookies is to maintain state between pages, and still a good skill to learn; but if you didn't need it, all the better!

Answer (score 3):

If you change the background via jQuery, remember that JS runs on client side.

Basically, it seems that the background changes but turns back as soon as the default `"onclick"` action is executed.

This happens because a redirect link just makes you jump in another page with another JS session.

You can fix this using cookies (jQuery plugin [HERE](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)) so each time that you change the page you read the value of the url of the background and you pick the next one.

Comment: I see now, there's a <a href> there, good catch, no wonder it's not working?

Comment: take a better look, there actually is an anchor inside that has `href="Environment.php"`

Comment: exactly ;) (for JS session i meant that if he's redirected to another page he simpy lose all the variables values used in that JS client session)

Answer (score 2):

> **ANOTHER UPDATE!!!** I don't know if it will help toward your end goal, but instead of trying to strain your brain to transition images and instead of using plain straight colors, you can use a **GREAT** gradient tool found [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to set your classes to use cross-browser compatible gradient transitions instead! Though a word of caution, i've found through testing, not all gradients transition well.
>
> ---
>
> **UPDATE** *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/pm2zN/)* made to show working example of changing **body** background color through jQueryUI's .toggleClass, still don't know if it will work with images tho

Just another note, try adding [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/download) to your jQuery and then see both of the following doc pages:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/
- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions

To get all the info you really need on this and to understand, toggle class is a part of the jQuery core, but the animation transition is added with jQuery ui and thus is only applicable to a certain extent of manipulation.  For instance, i've not tested what you're trying to achieve with a **body** background change so I can't say for sure this is your solution, but I do know changing an element background simple.

To do a simple element background change do the following:

> Example HTML i'm using

```
<div id="eleID" class="original"> some text </div>
<button id="btnChange">Change</button>​
```

> You'll need to establish an `original` class containing your base background and color settings & a `change` class of somesort containing you `alternate` background colors and text colors, like so:

```
.original{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
.change {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}​
```

And finally, your simple javascript would be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnChange").click(function(e) {
        $("#eleID").toggleClass( "change", 1000 );
    });
});
```